Random walk on the edges of a square where staying at same position is allowed
The classic question of finding the expected number of steps to move from one corner of a square to the opposite. I found an intuitive way to do it by considering that we are at position $(0,0)$ and wish to reach position $(1,1)$ and then looking at the Manhattan distance from the origin at each step.
For 2 steps this gives us:
$$0 \xrightarrow{1} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}}  2$$
The numbers above the arrows represent the probabilities of the transition.
Thus probability of reaching opposite corner (or point with Manhattan distance 2 from (0,0))  in 2 moves is $\frac{1}{2}$. It is not possible to reach $(1,1)$ in 3 (or any odd number) steps in this setting. Similarly for 4 moves we have the case:
$$0 \xrightarrow{1} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}} 0 \xrightarrow{1} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{2}}  2$$
which shows that the probability of reaching $(1,1)$ in 4 steps is $\frac{1}{4}$. Inductively we can show that the probability of reaching $(1,1)$ in $2 + n$, $n \geq 0$ steps is $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Thus the expected number of turns to reach $(1,1)$ is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2+2n}{2^{n+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1 + n}{2^{n}} = 4$$
My question:
What if we are allowed to stay at current position with equal probability?
Now using the same idea to go from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ in 2 steps we have,
$$0 \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$ thus the probability of 2 steps now is $\frac{2}{9}$. We can have 3 steps in this setting which gives us,
$$0\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 0 \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
$$0 \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
which gives us the probability $\frac{2 + 2}{27} = \frac{4}{27}$. This made it seem like the next should be $\frac{8}{81}$ for 4 steps but let's have a look at it,
$$ 0 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}}0  \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 0 \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
$$ 0  \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}}0 \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
$$0  \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}}1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 0  \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
$$0  \xrightarrow{\frac{2}{3}} 1\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}}1\xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 1 \xrightarrow{\frac{1}{3}} 2$$
This gives us the probability $\frac{2 + 2 + 4 + 2}{81} = \frac{10}{81}$. From this I am unable to see the pattern. How should I proceed? I am not familiar with Markov chains so I would like a simple and elegant way forward if possible.
(This is not homework or graded assessment. I saw a puzzle on random walks and thought of this modification for my own interest)
Edit: I know from a simple python simulation that the expected number of steps is $\approx 6$.

For the pattern you would have to consider that there are also different numbers of 1/3, 2/3 steps possible, next to looking at the order. But this is a s simple Markov chain indeed. See  this

@Henkie I don't think I follow. Can you elaborate?

Take for example 6 steps, that can happen with 6 real steps, 4 real steps or 2 real steps. Have to look at each, take for example the 4 real steps: the real steps will be always in this order:2/3 * 1/3 * 2/3 * 1/3.  But now you need to place 2 time 1/3 in between. There are 4 spots to place 2 equal things, that can be in $ \binom{4+ 2 -1 }{4-1}$ ways. So probability of 6 steps with 4 real steps is 2/31/32/3*1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * $ \binom{4+ 2 -1 }{4-1}$

@Henkie But my construction is already doing what you mentioned. Consider 4 steps. Either 2 real or 4 real steps. In the case of 2 real steps, the order is : $2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9$. Now we need to place 1/3 twice in between. There are ${ 2 + 2 -1 \choose 2 -1 } = {3 \choose 1}$ ways to do this. Thus the probability of doing 4 steps with 2 real steps is $3 * 2/9 * 1/9 = 6/81$ which is what I get above. I wish to know how the closed form of the probability in i steps and how to derive it.

Let $S$ be the total number of step and R be the number of real steps. Then the probability for i steps is:
$$\mathbb{P}(S=i)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}\mathbb{P}(S=i|R=2n)= \sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}(2/9)^n(1/ 3)^{i-2n}\binom{i-1}{2n-1} $$

thank you for your answer. Can you help me see how it is derived?

First we break it down by the number of real steps. It must always be an even number of real steps, so we sum over all even real steps smaller than i. For a given number of real steps 2n, the probabilities of the real steps are $(2/3\times1/3)^n$ and then we have $i-2n$ fake steps giving the probability $(1/3)^{i-2n}$. The binomial term is for the number of ways we can allocate the $i-2n$ fake steps in between the 4 real steps.

You are right that the new answer is $6$. Before every "useful" step that the walk makes, it makes an average of $0.5$ "fake" steps (i.e. steps where it stays at the same site). We know that the expected number of useful steps required to reach the goal is $4$. From this we get that the total expected number of steps needed is $4+4*0.5=6$.

Could you explain how we get 0.5 fake steps before every useful step? The probability of a useful step is 2/3, so the expected number of steps to see a useful step is 1.5. Are you concluding from this that it is expected that 1.5 - 1 = 0.5 "fake" steps have occurred?

Exactly. The average number of steps up to and including the useful step is 1.5. So the average number of steps up to and not including the useful step is 0.5. (I wouldn't personally say "it's expected that 0.5 fake steps have occurred" but some people do....)

That makes sense. Could you explain how would I proceed with my method?

There are quite a lot of ways to extend your method. People gave some combinatorial ideas above. Another is via simple Markov chain methods. Let $p_{00}^{(n)}$ and $p_{01}^{(n)}$ respectively be the probabilities of being at distance $0$ or $1$ from the start at time $n$ without having passed through distance $2$. Then you can solve a system of second-order linear recurrence equations $p_{00}^{(n)}=p_{00}^{(n-1)}/3+p_{01}^{(n-1)}/3$ and $p_{01}^{n}=p_{01}^{(n-1)}/3+2p_{00}^{(n)}/3$. Then the probability of getting to distance $2$ for the first time in exactly $n$ steps is $p_{01}^{(n-1)}/3$.

that makes sense. Thank you!
